# Strange byte when download to file JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, download, hex, byte

I'm trying to download a string to a file using the following function:

```
function handleDownload(){
  var settings = "";
  for (var i in archivo){
    settings += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(archivo[i], 16));
  }
  var blob=new Blob([settings], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
  var link=document.createElement('a');
  link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download="config.bin";
  link.click();
}
```

It's works fine but sometimes it adds the value '0xC2' in the middle.

For example, using the following byte array as input
`00 a0 42 00`
the file returns
`00 c2 a0 42 00`

How can I solve this? I checked the whole file and it's always a 0xC2 before a byte that it's greater than 127.

Thanks!

Comment: `(archivo[i]<16 ? "0" : "" ) + String.fromCharCode(parseInt(archivo[i], 16))`

Comment: What? The 'settings' string it's correctly loaded. I printed it in console to check and there is not 0xC2 char. The problem is in the download section. As I said, when the byte it's greater than 127, a 0xC2 it's added before.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I created an unsigned array (Uint8Array) and send it to the Blob.

```
var archivo =   ["7E","7F","80","81",
                 "7E","7F","80","81",
                 "7E","7F","80","81",
                 "7E","7F","80","81"];//126,127,128,129

function d(){
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(archivo.length);

    for (var i in archivo){
        bytes[i] = parseInt(archivo[i], 16);
    }

    var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "config.bin";
    link.click();
}
```